# display checked icon (ticks) for the already selected checkboxes. | Laravel | (Checkboxes, as in WordPress)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6, laravel-7

### I want to display checked icon (tick) for the already selected ones on the product update page

I want to **tick** the already selected ones on the **product update page**. If the Samsung category is already selected, it should be checked in this box.

How to do it?

[image]

I use many To many relationship.

in product model,

```
public function productcategories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(ProductCategory::class, 'product_category', 'product_id', 'category_id');
}
```

productCategory Model,

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_category', 'category_id', 'product_id');
}
```

in update view page,

```
                        @foreach ($productcategories as $category)
                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                            <div class="form-check">
                                <input class="form-check-input" name="productcategory_id[]" type="checkbox" value="{{$category->id}}">
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
                                    {{$category->name}}
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @foreach ($category->subcategory as $sub)
                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 ">
                            <div class="form-check">
                                {!! "&nbsp;" !!} {!! "&nbsp;" !!} {!! "&nbsp;" !!}
                                <input class="form-check-input" name="productcategory_id[]" type="checkbox"
                                    value="{{$sub->id}}">
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
                                    {{$sub->name}}
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @endforeach
                        @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

for check and unchecked you should be use boolean in your app and database a false or true... if is true, this will be check, if this is false no show a select or check in front